# "Property does not exist on type {}" error when using anonymous function with D3 SVG Symbol

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, symbols, powerbi

I'm trying to create D3 SVG Symbols, with the symbol shape set dynamically based on a category property in the data. This will be part of a custom visual in PowerBI, so I'm using Typings library.

From the examples I've seen online, the below code should work.

```
var milestoneSymbols = this.milestoneContainer.selectAll('.path').data(viewModel.milestones);
milestoneSymbols.enter().append('path');
milestoneSymbols.attr('d', d3.svg.symbol() 
                            .size(25) 
                            .type( function(d){ return d.typeSymbol})
    );
milestoneSymbols.attr("transform", function(d,i) {
        return "translate("+ xScale(d.date) + "," 
            + ((i % heightGroups) * (milestoneContainerHeight/heightGroups) + margins.top )
            + ")";
        });
milestoneSymbols.style("stroke", "function(d) {  return findTaskTypeShape(d.label).color; }
                .style("stroke-width", 1)
                .style("fill", function(d) {  return findTaskTypeShape(d.label).color; });
```

But I get the error `Property 'typeSymbol' does not exist on type '{}'` for the  code `.type( function(d){ return d.typeSymbol})`. It appears that `d` is not available inside `type()` because it's being used in the `d3.svg.symbol()` code. If I replace the anonymous function with a string literal like "square", it works.

How can this be fixed?

Comment: Can you show a minimum example with data?

Comment: It seems you are using typescript. Are you getting a compile error or a run-time error?

Comment: I'm getting a compile error:  `error  TYPESCRIPT  /src/timeline.ts : (609,70) Property 'typeSymbol' does not exist on type '{}'.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typescript does not know anything about your data object type. You can define the data object type or you could try to use the type any:

```
milestoneSymbols.attr('d', d3.svg.symbol() 
                            .size(25) 
                            .type( function(d: any){ return d.typeSymbol;})
```