# Typescript type against '{}'

Tags: angular, typescript, d3.js

I'm getting a type error for curly brackets in Angular2, interacting with D3:

`.attr("cy", function (data) { return x([data.lon,data.lat])[1]; })`

The error is:

```
error TS2339: Property 'lon' does not exist on type '{}'
error TS2339: Property 'lat' does not exist on type '{}'
```

the `attr` line is inside a function and `x` is an alias of `let x = this.projection;` `this.projection` returns a fucntion. `data` *is* the an object.

`circles` are added initialy by calling a method with data passed to it (nothing errors here):

```
drawMarkers(map,stations,projection) {
        map.selectAll("circle")
        .data(stations)
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
        .attr("cx", function (d) { return projection([d.lon,d.lat])[0]; })
        .attr("cy", function (d) { return projection([d.lon,d.lat])[1]; })
        .attr("r", "1px")
        .attr("fill", "white")
        .attr('style','cursor: pointer;')
        .on('click',() => {
            this.flyoutservice.changeFlyoutState(true);
        });
    }
```

When zoomed a "zoom" function is called and the `circles` are redrawn to the new location (this is where the error happens):

```
map
        .selectAll('circle')
        .attr("cx", function (data) { return x([data.lon,data.lat])[0]; })
        .attr("cy", function (data) { return x([data.lon,data.lat])[1]; })
        .attr('r',(d) => {
            let cr = parseInt(d3.select(this).attr('r'), 10);

            let scale = d3.event.transform['k'];

            return 1 / d3.event.transform['k'];
        });
```

The error fires when compiled but runtime works/runs just fine.

If I do this: `.attr("cx", function (data) { return x([data['object'].lon['number'],data['object'].lat['number'])[0]; })` my compile error goes away but I get an error at runtime that `lon` cannot read property of undefined. However, everything runs fine despite that error.

Comment: How is data defined?  What is it's type?

Comment: @Mark I added more context

Comment: Also, the overall data is being pulled in via service I'm subscribed to that's just json.

Comment: I would say do a `console.log(data)` and you will find your error

Comment: Ok, this looks to be a duplicate [of this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40954169/16363).  Although, it would be better if you based used a real type instead of `any`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried defining the type for `data` in your `attr` functions so Typescript recognises it as a property?

```
.attr("cx", (data: { lon: number, lat: number }) => { return x([data.lon,data.lat])[0]; })
.attr("cy", (data: { lon: number, lat: number }) => { return x([data.lon,data.lat])[1]; })
```

For consistency, i'd also change the first function in the same way:

```
.attr("cx", (d: { lon: number, lat: number }) => { return projection([d.lon,d.lat])[0]; })
.attr("cy", (d: { lon: number, lat: number }) => { return projection([d.lon,d.lat])[1]; })
```

Comment: Nice, +1, but I'd say its safe to assume that `lon` and `lat` are of type `number`, which is preferable to giving them type `any`, since it will allow typescript to continue type checking their usage.

Comment: Good point. I'd thrown in `any` incase the `lat`/`lon` came back as `string` from the service and had to be parsed first. But you're probably right that it'd be a `number`. At least if it does come back as a `string`, TS will throw an error and point that out. Edited to reflect.